# Showing RSS feeds in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-6.2

There is RSS portlet in Liferay 6.2. There is option of providing URL for feeds. But I want to have feeds(.rss files) from my Linux server(same server on which Liferay is running). Is it possible?

Comment: With enough enthusiasm nearly everything is possible. As stackoverflow is for programming questions only, I'd guess that you mean "Is it possible to adjust the RSS portlet to support a local file?". Yes that is possible. But if you instead wanted to know "Is it possible to enter a local file URL in the RSS portlet", then you should try it yourself first (`file://...`) and add the results to your question.

Comment: @Tobias Liefke a bit confused with the 2 options you provided. I am looking for 1st one. RSS supporting local file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example did you try option 2 first: Enter a `file://...` URL into the RSS portlet configuration? What has happened? Where is your exact problem? With my first sentence I tried to indicate that your question is to broad, please narrow it down.